# How to create the history of particular field of content

Tags: views

I have a content type called Fruitera, which has a select list **field_fruits**, which has these possible options:

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Orange
4. Pineapple

For this I have created a view, and now I want to see the history of particular **field_fruits**.

Whenever we edit the content it will replaced by another fruit, I want to see previous history of **field_fruits** for content created in a view.

Any suggestions know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried revisioning?

Comment: @Huelfe: yes...revisioning is only for content type and when we click on particular node saved if we edit that it shows previous version of content. here in my case i want to click on field and its not a node, when i click on it i would like to see the previous fruit chosen for that node.

Answer (score 1):

[Track Field Changes](https://www.drupal.org/project/track_field_changes) is a module that allows you to easily enable tracking/auditing on changes to fields, and has views integration.

I hope this will make your work.

Comment: Thank you so much....i will try with this and get back to you.

Comment: i tried and in view i could not track athe field though i have enabled the field track changes for particular field.please can you tell me where i am doing mistake...

Comment: I could not see where exactly i can see  all this changes  or edit made for field...

Comment: Have you carefully followed the usage step mentioned on https://www.drupal.org/project/track_field_changes ??

Comment: yes i have followed....i dont know what mistake i am doing....this is what i did...1] installation and enable 2] admin->config->system->track field changes-> here enable the content type-> under enable field for which i want to  track. I am i wrong?